# Where to accept the Terms of Service for Google Play App Signing in the Play Store?

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-console, android-app-signing

I'm desperately trying to opt out of Google Play App Signing. However the opt out button is gone until I accept the Terms of Service:

[image: Google Play App Signing Settings]

With the account owner I was searching for the Terms of Service, but we couldn't find it. Where is that accept button hidden in the Play Store?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Found it - there is a menu entry:

[image]

Answer (score 12):

In the new Play Developer Console you can accept the Terms of Service by selecting your app then scroll down to the bottom of the navigation options in the left panel.  Select Internal App Sharing.  If you haven't already accepted the terms then you will be shown a link where you can agree to the ToS!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have the app created the only way is to have an account with admin or owner permissions in order to create a new app and accept the app signing terms of service.
You can either request admin permissions or ask the appropriate account holder to create the app for you.
(at the time of writing)